# Click on Image src using Python Selenium which do not have element id

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have arrows in the webpage which will expand and take me to the next, and so on. Manually, if i click on that arrow, it expands and shows me the breakdown.

[image]

I am trying to automate the same using Python Selenium module, trying to click on the arrow before "User Directory". When i see the code in developer option (F12), it shows me class name, Image title and src. I tried to get the list of text using class names:-

[image]

```
a=[]
a=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("bi-tree-view-expand-icon")
print(a)
```

But every time the session and elements i get differs. Output is below:

> ```
> > [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> > (session="98f30ad2-4ff3-42fa-985e-206c0a778ee8",
> > element="270e9246-ee5c-44da-8348-94047ca5d633")>,
> > <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> > (session="98f30ad2-4ff3-42fa-985e-206c0a778ee8",
> > element="b53fd15f-6c2d-4d8c-9f37-c79803d5b2fc")>,
> > <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> > (session="98f30ad2-4ff3-42fa-985e-206c0a778ee8",
> > element="74f4980e-3cd4-466d-972c-85a3d79de59d")>]
> ```

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, rather printing `a` click on it.

```
a[1].click()
```

However, we can streamline the xpath, provider you can share the html of the `user directories` parent element (including the children).

As you are returning all the elements matching with the `bi-tree-view-expand-icon` class name, there are multiple expand icons and when you print `a` list a collection of elements. so you are seeing all expand icons references. If you want to access particular expand icon you can use the index or write more precise xpath.

Comment: You nailed it!!!!!!! Since it was the first element, i had to change your code to 'a[0].click()'

Comment: I got it through for one group. But for another group, i am stuck. The only difference i can see is "Expand" and "Collapse" 

Main Group
'<img title="Collapse" class="bi-tree-view-expand-icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.m/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree-view-minus.gif">'